# Python program works from command prompt but does not work when opened in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am working on a very simple python program that is basically a password entry screen. Everything is working as it should and the program runs correctly when I execute through the command prompt on Windows (python login.py). However, if I run the program by double clicking it, it takes me as far as the "Enter password: " input and as soon as I hit enter with my desired password, it gives this error:

NameError: name 'pass' is not defined.

How do I go about fixing this error?

```
import time

print("You have ten seconds to enter the password.")
time.sleep(1)
print("Or this computer will shut down.")
password = input("Enter password: ")

while 1:
    if password == "pass":
        print("Login successful.")
        break
    else:
        password = input("Enter password: ")
```

Comment: I suspect you're using Python 2.x in one instance and 3.x in the other - `input` in Python 2 is `eval(raw_input(...))`, so is trying to resolve `pass` as an identifier, not a string.

Comment: Odd, I uninstalled Python 2.7 (I had both 2 and 3 installed) and that appears to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running Python 3.X from the command line, but Python 2.7 is executing your script when you click on it. The error occurs because 2.7's `input` behaves differently from 3.X's.

You could try to redefine `input` so it behaves the same in both versions:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    #we're already in 3.x and don't need to do anything
    pass

#rest of code goes here
```

---

Alternatively, you could change the default application for .py files. How this is done probably varies from OS to OS, but in Windows it's something like: right click the .py file, choose "open with..." and "choose default program", then browse to the python executable in your 3.X directory.

Comment: For Windows Python 3.3+, start an elevated command prompt to run  `ftype Python.File="path\to\py.exe" "%1" %*`. Typically the launcher path is `C:\Windows\py.exe`. A script can ensure it runs using Python 3 by adding a virtual shebang line such as `#!/usr/bin/python3`. To instead  make 2.x the system default -- without the shebang-aware py.exe launcher -- just use the path to `python.exe`.

Comment: The "open with" approach creates a broken ProgId that lacks `%*` for command-line arguments.